# Need records from one table but a column from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query that will return a table with all rows from only one table, `Current Open Orders Today`, but return the ship date as of `yesterday` from `Open Orders From Yesterday` for each record in the `Current Open Orders Today` table. I don't want any excess records from `Open Orders From Yesterday`. However, right now it's returning the incorrect number of rows I'm assuming because of my join or something.

Any recommendations on how to return ONLY the records from the `Current Open Orders Today` table but still return the ship date as of `yesterday` from the `Open Orders From Yesterday` for each record would be appreciated!

Here is the SQL code for my query:

```
SELECT [Current Open Orders Today].[Customer Code], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Customer Name], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Sales Order Number], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Input By], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Customer PO Number], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Date Received], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Date Entered], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Date Required], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Date Promised], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Ship Date as of Today],
       [Open Orders From Yesterday].[Ship Date] AS [Ship Date from Yesterday], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].WAREHOUSE, 
       [Current Open Orders Today].Product, 
       [Current Open Orders Today].Alpha, 
       [Current Open Orders Today].Description, 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Long Description], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Order Quantity], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Order Value], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Customer Analysis], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].Territory, 
       [Current Open Orders Today].Engineer, 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Analysis Code 5], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].[Industrial Class], 
       [Current Open Orders Today].Region, 
       [Current Open Orders Today].Status
FROM [Current Open Orders Today] 
INNER JOIN [Open Orders From Yesterday] 
   ON ([Current Open Orders Today].[Sales Order Number] = [Open Orders From Yesterday].[Sales Order Number]) 
  AND ([Current Open Orders Today].Product = [Open Orders From Yesterday].Product);
```

Comment: scroll for days.  You should break your query up so it can actually be read :P

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Thanks for editing JaydipJ! Much appreciated

Comment: Try to make your query simpler. You dont need include all the fields  and try to use alias.

Comment: Well all the salesman that I'm making this table for want all of those columns; they need that info so I can't reduce the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You're joining all today orders with all yesterday orders.

Build your command without join part

```
select
    today.*
    , (select top 1 yesterday.[ship_date] 
        from [yesterday open orders] 
        where yesterday.order number = today.order number 
        and yesterday.product code = today.product code)
from
    [current open orders today]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `LEFT JOIN`, So that it will select all rows from `[Current Open Orders Today]` and only matching rows from `[Open Orders From Yesterday]`.

```
SELECT C.[Customer Code], 
       C.[Customer Name], 
       C.[Sales Order Number], 
       C.[Input By], 
       C.[Customer PO Number], 
       C.[Date Received], 
       C.[Date Entered], 
       C.[Date Required], 
       C.[Date Promised], 
       C.[Ship Date as of Today],
       O.[Ship Date] AS [Ship Date from Yesterday], 
       C.WAREHOUSE, 
       C.Product, 
       C.Alpha, 
       C.Description, 
       C.[Long Description], 
       C.[Order Quantity], 
       C.[Order Value], 
       C.[Customer Analysis], 
       C.Territory, 
       C.Engineer, 
       C.[Analysis Code 5], 
       C.[Industrial Class], 
       C.Region, 
       C.Status
FROM [Current Open Orders Today] C
LEFT JOIN [Open Orders From Yesterday] O
   ON (C.[Sales Order Number] = O.[Sales Order Number]) 
  WHERE O.[Ship Date] = getdate() - 1 /*Gets All records from Yeterday's date*/
  AND (C.Product = O.Product);
```

Comment: I had tried left join before and it still wasn't returning the correct number of rows; still too many. I need ONLY rows from current open orders today, no excess rows from the other table. I just need the ship date as of yesterday from the other table to match up to the records from current open orders today.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [coot].[Customer Code], 
   [coot].[Customer Name], 
   [coot].[Sales Order Number], 
   [coot].[Input By], 
   [coot].[Customer PO Number], 
   [coot].[Date Received], 
   [coot].[Date Entered], 
   [coot].[Date Required], 
   [coot].[Date Promised], 
   [coot].[Ship Date as of Today],

   (select max([coft].[Ship Date]) from [Open Orders From Yesterday] as coft
     where ([coot].[Sales Order Number] = [coft].[Sales Order Number]) 
        AND ([coot].Product = [coft].Product)) AS [Ship Date from Yesterday] 
FROM [Current Open Orders Today] as coot
```